# Cracking the coding interview #9.3: magic index algorithm

Tags: python

I am currently doing this problem from the book cracking the coding interview:

9.3. A magic index in an array A[0...n-1] is defined to be an index such that
A[i] = i. Given a sorted array of distinct integers, write a method to find a
magic index, if one exists, in array A.

And here is my code:

```
def magic_index(seq, start = None, end = None):
    if start is None:
        start = 0

    if end is None:
        end = len(seq) - 1

    if start > end:
        return -1

    index = (start + end) // 2
    if index == seq(index):
        print("Equal to index. Value of index = " + index)
        return index

    if index > seq[index]:
        print("Greater than loop. Value of Index =" + index)
        return magic_index(seq, start=index + 1, end=end)
    else:
        print("Else part of Greater. Value of index = " + index)
        return magic_index(seq, start=start, end=index - 1)


def main():
    magic_index(seq=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], start=None, end=None).
```

However, when i run my code. I am not getting the proper output. Is there any help or advice I could get? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked for me once the syntax errors were fixed, namely:

- Access arrays using `[]` not `()`
- Call print with `%` and not `+`

Once those are fixed, the following worked as I would expect:

```
def magic_index(seq, start = None, end = None):
    if start is None:
        start = 0

    if end is None:
        end = len(seq) - 1

    if start > end:
        return -1

    index = (start + end) // 2
    if index == seq[index]: # array indexing with `[]` not `()`
        print("Equal to index. Value of index = %s" % index) # use % to print index
        return index

    if index > seq[index]:
        print("Greater than loop. Value of Index = %s" % index)
        return magic_index(seq, start=index + 1, end=end)
    else:
        print("Else part of Greater. Value of index = %s" % index)
        return magic_index(seq, start=start, end=index - 1)


def main():
    result = magic_index(seq=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], start=None, end=None)
    if result == -1:
        print('No Result Found!')
```

The output was `No Result Found` which is correct for the provided array.

```
print magic_index(seq=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], start=None, end=None)
# prints 2
print magic_index(seq=[0, 2, 4, 6], start=None, end=None)
# prints 0
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to account for non-distinct integers (which the book states as a follow up)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your syntax errors, try this:

```
def magic_index(seq, start = None, end = None):
  if start is None:
    start = 0

  if end is None:
    end = len(seq) - 1

  if(start > end or start < 0 or end >= len(seq)):
    return -1

  index = (start + end) // 2

  if(seq[index] == index):
    print("Equal to index. Value of index = %d" % index)
    return index

  if(seq[index] < index):
    print("Greater than loop. Value of Index = %d" % index)
    return magic_index(seq, index + 1, index)

  return magic_index(seq, start, index - 1)
```